# Error adding right-click menu Edit option

Tags: windows-xp, file-types, dde

I've followed the [**instructions**](http://www.superlogical.net/computing/windows/2011/07/add-edit-with-to-right-click-menu/) to add an entry to the right-click menu, to add "Edit with Paint.NET" to the jpg right-click menu.

However, Paint.NET produces the error:

[image]

(The image type is not recognized, and cannot be opened.)

I've double checked that the same menu option applies to both JPG and JPEG, and I've turned DDE off, but the error remain.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm pretty sure it's suppose to be a %1 and not %.